# Multiple Y-Axis Legend on single data with plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plot, legend, plotly

I'am willing to display two legends (relative and absolute scales) on a graphic using plotly js. To do so I may use this piece of code:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [40, 50, 60],
  name: 'absolute',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [4, 5, 6],
  name: 'relative',
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Double Y Axis',
  yaxis: {title: 'absolute'},
  yaxis2: {
    title: 'relative',
    overlaying: 'y',
    side: 'right'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

But it basically draws twice the same line, which I don't want. Is their a cheaper way to add a scale + legend on the right side of my graph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with plotly.
Using a enhanced chart library such as ngx-charts however, may solve your problem